# in insufficiently-polymorphic why are there less ways to implement `List a -> List a -> List a` then `List Char -> List Char -> List Char`

Tags: scala, functional-programming

in [insufficiently-polymorphic](http://degoes.net/articles/insufficiently-polymorphic)

the author says about:
`def foo[A](fst: List[A], snd: List[A]): List[A]`

> There are fewer ways we can implement the function. In particular, we
>   can’t just hard-code some elements in a list, because we have no
>   ability to manufacture values of an arbitrary type.

I did not understand this, because also in the `[Char]` version we had no ability to manufacture values of an arbitrary type we had to have them of type `[Char]` so why are there less ways to implement this?

Comment: I'm assuming the author means, that there's no way to construct a `List a` but there's a way to construct a `List Char`, e.g. by using a String literal. You could just ignore the arguments and just return a hard-coded String.

Comment: Why do people keep putting the `haskell` tag on this? It seems to be purely about Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the generic version you know that the output list can only contain some arrangement of the elements contained in `fst` and `snd` since there is no way to construct new values of some arbitrary type `A`. In contrast, if you know the output type is `Char` you can e.g.

```
def foo(fst: List[Char], snd: List[Char]) = List('a', 'b', 'c')
```

In addition you cannot use the values contained in the input lists to make decisions which affect the output, since you don't know what they are. You can do this if you know the input type e.g.

```
def foo(fst: List[Char], snd: List[Char]) = fst match {
    case Nil => snd
    case 'a'::fs => snd
    case _ => fst
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming the author means, that there's no way to construct a non-empty `List a` but there's a way to construct a `List Char`, e.g. by using a String literal. You could just ignore the arguments and just return a hard-coded String.
An example of this would be:

```
foo :: List Char -> List Char -> List Char
foo a b = "Whatever"
```

You can't construct a value of an arbitrary type `a`, but you can construct a value of type `Char`.

Comment: There _is_ a way to construct a `List a`, namely `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple case of a property called ["parametricity"](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) or "free theorem", which applies to every polymorphic function.

An even simpler example is the following:

```
fun1 :: Int -> Int
fun2 :: forall a. a -> a
```

`fun1` can be anything: successor, predecessor, square, factorial, etc. This is because it can "read" its input, and act accordingly.

`fun2` *must* be the identity function (or loop forever). This because `fun2` receives its input, but it can not examine it in any useful way: since it is of an abstract, unknown type `a`, no operations can be performed on it. The input is effectively an opaque token. The output of `foo2` must be of type `a`, for which we do not know any construction means -- we can not create a value of type `a` from nothing. The only option is to take the input `a` and use it to craft the output `a`. Hence, `fun2` is the identity.

The above parametricity result holds when you have no way to perform tests on the input or the type `a`. If we, e.g., allowed `if x.instanceOf[Int] ...`, or `if x==null ...`, or type casts (in OOP) then we could write `fun2` in other ways.

Comment: so cool!! it always appeared to me like generics make the code be able to do more things :) now i get it can make the code do less things.

Comment: @Jas Fun exercise: guess which functions can have `fun3 :: forall a. a -> a -> a` -- only a few options apply here.

Comment: how should I think of `a -> a -> a` i'm currently thinking of it as function with two arguments and one return value is this the right way? (with the same type for all)

Comment: @Jas Yes, and all of them are of type `a`